# Call the upload file

Tags: php

In html I have an upload button for a photo:

```
 <p>
   <input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
 </p>
 <br>
 <p>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
  </p>
```

After that I want to take the results using the echo and insert the result in a table in the center of page.

I made this but it is not working properly. Any suggestion?

```
  <table align="center">
  <tr>
      <?php echo $_POST['datafile']; ?>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    print_r($_FILES); // you will get your data in $_FILES variable.
}

?>
<form action="file_upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <p>
    <input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
 </p>
 <br>
 <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
 </p>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have enctype="multipart/form-data in your form tag

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And get the uploaded file via $_FILES: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
$_FILES['datafile']
```

Read more here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp